# Django not releasing memory

Tags: django, memory

Based on other posts I understand Django doesn't have a memory leak issue but I have a web application where when I specific routine is called, a lot of memory is getting used but not all of it is freed up afterwards.  I don't know if that is the correctly terminology but if I track the mem_used_perc on AWS while only calling this routine on the webpage I see the memory usage increase and not return to previous levels.

It is a recursive routine that I call which can iterate up to 7 times.  This is the code:

```
def autosearch(self, phase=1, report="", num = 10):
        """
        This is an ES search following specific rules to identify and populate
        the lead notifications
        """
     
        if phase == 1:
            self.referred_to.clear()
            if self.no_of_providers:
                num = self.no_of_providers
            else:
                num = 10

        sqs = OrganisationDocument.search()

        service_type = None
        # filter by care type
        if self.type_of_care_care_home:
            service_type = "service_care_home"
        elif self.type_of_care_home_care:
            service_type = "service_home_care"
        elif self.type_of_care_live_in_care:
            service_type = "service_live_in_care"
        elif self.type_of_care_retirement_village:
            service_type = "service_retirement_village"

        if service_type == "service_retirement_village":
            sqs = sqs.query(Q("multi_match", query=True, fields=service_type))
        elif service_type:
            sqs = sqs.query(
                Q("multi_match", query=True, fields=service_type)
                & Q("match", care_over_65=True)
            )
        else:
            sqs = sqs.query(Q("match", care_over_65=True))

        if self.budget_type:
            ranges = self.filter_by_budget_range(phase)
            sqs = sqs.query(Q("bool", should=list(ranges)))
        
        # filter on location and distance
        if self.radius:
            radius = self.radius
        else:
            radius = 5

        """Increase radius by 2 or 10% for phase 2, 5, and 6"""
        if phase in [2, 6]:
            if radius < 20:
                radius += 2
            else:
                radius *= 1.1
        sqs = sqs.query(
                "geo_distance",
                distance=f"{radius}mi",
                location={
                    "lat": self.searcharea_set.all()[0].lat,
                    "lon": self.searcharea_set.all()[0].lng,
                },
            ) 
       
        # Filter by care_category_type
        categories = []
        if self.care_need_category_residential:
            categories.append("care_residential")
        if self.care_need_category_nursing:
            categories.append("care_nursing")
        if self.care_need_category_dementia:
            categories.append("care_dementia")
        if self.care_need_category_nursing_dementia:
            pass
        if self.care_need_category_personal_care:
            categories.append("care_residential")
        if self.care_need_category_respite_care:
            categories.append("care_respite")
        if self.care_need_palliative:
            pass
        if self.care_need_end_of_life:
            pass
        if self.care_need_retirement_housing:
            categories.append("retirement_living_housing")
        if self.care_need_retirement_village:
            categories.append("retirement_living_village")
        if self.care_need_retirement_community:
            categories.append("retirement_living_community")
        if self.care_need_retirement_full_time:
            pass

        query = []
        for category in categories:
            if self.type_of_care_live_in_care or self.type_of_care_home_care:
                if category == "care_residential":
                    category = "regulated_personal_care"

            if category == "care_nursing":
                query.append(
                    Q(
                        Q("match", regulated_nursing_care=True)
                        | Q("match", care_nursing=True)
                    )
                )
            else:
                query.append(Q("match", **{f"{category}": True}))

        if self.type_of_care_retirement_village:
            sqs = sqs.query("bool", should=list(query))
        else:
            sqs = sqs.filter(Q("bool", must=query))

        # CQC Regulator filter
        sqs = sqs.query(
            Q(
                Q("match", cqc_rating_overall=1)
                | Q("match", cqc_rating_overall=2)
                | Q("match", cqc_rating_overall=3)
                | Q("match", cqc_rating_overall=99)
            )
        )

        # filter on profile
        if phase >= 4:
            sqs = sqs.query(Q("match", has_thumbnail_image=1))
            # Exclude Standard profiles in Brand with Premium Profile
            prems = [x.id for x in self.referred_to.all() if x.is_premium]
            sqs = sqs.query(~Q('bool', brand_link=list(prems)))
        else:
            sqs = sqs.query(Q("match", is_premium=1))
        
        # filter on budget
        if self.budget_type:
            ranges = self.filter_by_budget_range(phase)
            sqs = sqs.query(Q("bool", should=list(ranges)))

        # funding method
        if self.funding_method == choices.LOCAL_AUTHORITY:
            sqs = sqs.query(~Q("match", fees_local_authority_funded=False))
            # sqs = sqs.query('match', **{'fees_local_authority_funded': True})
        elif self.funding_method == choices.SELF_FUNDING:
            sqs = sqs.query("match", self_funding_clients=True)
        elif self.funding_method == choices.CONTINUING_HEALTHCARE:
            sqs = sqs.query(Q("match", fees_continuous_health_top_up=True))
        elif self.funding_method == choices.TOP_UP:
            sqs = sqs.query(~Q("match", fees_family_top_up=False))

        # Red crossed
        sqs = sqs.query(~Q("match", autumna_flag=2))
        # amber flagged
        if phase < 7:
            sqs = sqs.query(~Q("match", autumna_flag=1))

        # email only
        if not self.may_contact_provider:
            sqs = sqs.query(~Q("match", leads_accepted=1))
            sqs = sqs.query(~Q("match", leads_accepted=2))

        # no permission
        if not self.may_contact_phone:
            sqs = sqs.query(~Q("match", leads_accepted=1))

        # timescales
        if self.timescales in ["ASAP", "2-4 weeks"]:
            sqs = sqs.query(
                Q(
                    Q("match", availability_overall=1)
                    | Q("match", availability_overall=2)
                )
            )
    
        sqs.sort("-is_premium", "-has_thumbnail_image", "-is_claimed", self.sort_geo_location_dict())
        sqs = sqs[:num]

        report += f"<p>Phase {phase}:"
        added_count = 0
        for organisation in sqs.to_queryset():
            if not organisation in self.referred_to.all():
                added_count += 1
                self.referred_to.add(organisation)
                report += f"{organisation}, "
        report += "</p>"

        if added_count >= num or phase >= 7:
            self.autosearch_interim_report = report
            self.save()
        else:
            phase += 1
            num -= added_count
            return self.autosearch(phase, report, num)
        return True
```

Is there any reason this should cause the symptoms I am seeing and how do I fix it?

**EDIT**

The function is invoked from admin with the following:

```
def autosearch(self, request, pk):
    """
    Populates the lead notifications
    """
    lead = get_object_or_404(models.Lead, pk=pk)

    # first, add organisations to favourites
    result = lead.autosearch()
    logger.debug(f'Auto search result: {result}')

    return redirect(reverse("admin:lead_management_lead_change", args=(pk,)))
```

**EDIT**

I am using Memcache which is defined as follows:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache",
        "LOCATION": os.environ.get("CACHE_LOCATION", "127.0.0.1:11211"),
    }
}
```

So locally I run it on the machine but in production I am using an environment variable in Elastic Beanstalk to define `CACHE_LOCATION` which is a string something like: `my-site-name-prod.abcdef.cfg.euw2.cache.amazonaws.com:11211`

**EDIT**

```
def filter_by_budget_range(self, phase):
    """
    How the function works:
        - case 1: When a given value of min and max budget
                - It simply filter organisations between this range.

        - case 2: When a given value is only max budget
            - From given max budget we derived the min budget
                - min_budget = max_budget - max_budget * 0.2
                - e.g max_budget = 100, then the min_budget = 100 - 100 * 0.2 => 80

        - case 3: When a given value is only min budget
            - From given min budget we derived the max budget
                - max_budget = min_budget + min_budget * 0.2
                - e.g min_budget = 100, then the max_budget = 100 + 100 * 0.2 => 120
    """
   
    _budget_min, _budget_max = self.min_max_handler(phase)        
    if _budget_max is not None:
        if self.type_of_care_live_in_care or self.type_of_care_care_home:
            yield {
                "range": {
                    "fees_weekly_residential_costs_from": {
                        "gte": _budget_min * 100,
                        "lte": _budget_max * 100,
                    }
                }
            }      
        else:
            yield {
                "range": {
                    "fees_hourly_start_from": {
                        "gte": _budget_min * 100,
                        "lte": _budget_max * 100,
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I assume `autosearch()` is a method of a model, which is called as `instance.autosearch()`. How is `instance` used? Does it still exist when you check the memory?

Comment: It is a method of a model.  It is called from admin.  I do not know how to check if it still exists - all I can see if big jumps in the amount of memory used on the AWS graphs

Comment: @HenryM, please share the view/function where this method initially invoked

Comment: There is no abvious memory leak in your code. Can you reproduce this issue locally with the development server or only on production on AWS?

Comment: how is your django application deployed? Using gunicorn? using another wsgi module e.g. in apache? What process exactly is using all the memory?

Comment: I have both Apache and Nginx deployments and both seem the same

Comment: Can you use [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)? It may help identify what is causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the provided code that could explain a memory leak.

The issue must come from somewhere else (possibly `self.filter_by_budget_range(phase)`).

More often than not, memory leaks in Django would come from side-effects when using objects that are created at server startup, and that you keep feeding with new data without even realizing it, or without being aware that the object is bound to the server and not to single requests.

For instance, if you have something like that:

```py
class Foobar(models.Model):
    ...
    baz = ""
    ...

    def barfoo(self, baz):
        ...
        self.baz += baz
        ...
```

For every request where you call `obj.barfoo(some_string)`, `Foobar.baz` will keep growing until the server is restarted.

Similarily, in the following example:

```py
def foobar(baz=[]):
    ...
    baz.append(something)
    ...
```

Where the function `foobar` is created once at server startup. Every time you call `foobar()` with the default argument, `baz` keeps growing until the server is restarted.

These two examples are of course silly, it's just to show simple cases of side-effects affecting the memory.

---

Another possible issue would be if you cache some stuff using a memory-based backend such as Memcached.

---

If you have no idea what it could be, your best bet would probably be to try to reproduce the issue in development and use `pdb` (or even `django-pdb`) to inspect the memory, either while running the development server or directly in the shell (which could be more handy if you can reproduce in the shell).

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you manually run  gc.collect in your code?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html

`collect(): This method free the non referenced object in the list that is maintained by the Collector. Some non-referenced objects are not immediately free automatically due to their implementation.`

==============================================

Are you sure your issue is with the memory not being freed up again?
Are you having any memory issues?

In linux it is typical for memory to remain used even after the program has freed it again, since, wat good is your RAM if you keep it empty all the time.
The OS will keep things cached in RAM even if your application doesn't really need it at the moment, because it might benefit from increased performance when later on the application wants that data again and it is still in your ram.

This is called: caching

I tried looking up the documentation of the mem_used[_percent] call and it was not really clear to me if that meant in use memory (by applications + caches) or memory used by applications
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html

Do you have any issues with free memory? is your server going out of memory?

e.g. is mem_available and mem_free going back up after the call is done or not?

What you can typically see is memory being used by an application, then freed, but cashed by the os.

So mem_free goes back up, but it is cashed in memory, so mem_cached is going up, and mem_used stays the same.

This could explain what you are seeing without having a memory leak.

e.g. on my current system what I am seeing when I do `cat /proc/meminfo` I see almost no memory Free, but most of it (68%) is taken up by caches wich will be cleared as soon as an application needs memory.

```
   1   │ MemTotal:       16068712 kB
   2   │ MemFree:          178332 kB
   3   │ MemAvailable:   10290764 kB
   4   │ Buffers:          812504 kB
   5   │ Cached:         10203120 kB
   6   │ SwapCached:         1596 kB
   7   │ Active:          4852664 kB
   8   │ Inactive:       10034536 kB
```

Comment: The memory_used appears to only not go back down on this one call.  The server eventually crashes because there is no memory left.  Neither memory_free nor memory_available is going back down

Comment: @HenryM thank you for confirming, I have updated my answer, did you try gc.collect?